# Symfony production logs

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

In Symfony 3 is there anyway i can write all errors to logs on production without setting the debug mode on? Errors would include http 500 errors or application errors or the php errors which are silenced due to the error flag set to false on production.

The current log config for production is

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: info
            channels: [!request, !event, !translation, !kernel, !security, !php, !snc_redis]
       php:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_php.log"
            level: warning
            channels: [php]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the default production settings (taken from the [monolog-bundle recipe](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/monolog-bundle/3.1/config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml)) for this:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: nested
            excluded_404s:
                # regex: exclude all 404 errors from the logs
                - ^/
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
```

What happens with this configuration is that Monolog buffers all messages during a request, but only writes them to the log when an error appears. This way you will not "flood" your logs with noisy debug and info messages all the time. You only get full log information when there was an error during a request.

Comment: thanks this is good to know.. ill give this a go and feedback.. also the 'excluded_404s' is i am guessing a custom parameter name right? So i could potentially also create say a 'excluded_localhost' with a pattern say - '(127\.0\.0\.1) (ignore pattern) as an additional exclude?