# Symfony doesn't give full traces of Exceptions in production

Tags: php, symfony

We recently moved our infra to K8s, and since I have issue to get Traces of my Exceptions

We're on Symfony 3.4, and my Exception traces only gaves me `web/app.php`, but not root cause

```
Error: Call to a member function send() on null
#0 web/app.php(19): null
```

app.php is classic Symfony file, nothing relevent inside:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I tried to connect my localhost to my production DB, to see if I had the same issue, but no. I have correct full trace of my Exception

[image]

If I try in production with "app_dev.php" (which I enabled only for this test), I have same issue with no trace

[image]

Do you know what could cause this issue?
A PHP configuration? I checked differences between `php -i` on previous infra & new one, but I don't see any relevant difference

Edit:

Monolog in `config.yml`:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:      rotating_file
            max_files: 10
            path: '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.general.log'
            level: INFO
            formatter: myapp.monolog.formatter.json_message
```

Edit 2:
We bring part of old infra alive. And here the difference :
Old infra, for Fatal Errors, we have the full trace:
[image]
On new infra, same fatal error is displayed without any more detail
[image]

Comment: I think it's the expected behaviour, it's in production, showing stacktraces would be a security issue

Comment: @Lk77 With tools like https://sentry.io/ we always got all our traces. The traces are in the logs, not displayed in browser

Comment: I mean showing it to the end user, i'm not talking about sentry or other tools like that

Comment: We never show it to the end user. Actually it's a blank page. Even Symfony error page are not working.
The screenshot with red I posted comes from app_dev.php which is not available for end user

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49093078/symfony-production-logs

Comment: What does your Monolog config look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to comes from datadog agent that we added on our new infra.

Edit: Issue has been fixed in https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-php/releases/tag/0.79.0